# JQUERY popUp div, check variable before close

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, dialog

```
function InvokePage() {
    var layerDlg = $("#Layer").dialog({
        position: { my: "top", at: "bottom", of: $("header") },
        height: "auto",
        width: "auto",
        maxWidth: 400,
        modal: true,
        appendTo: "form",
        resizable: false,
        open: function (){},
        beforeclose: function()
        {
            var a = 1;
        },
        close: function () {
            if (g_changesMade) {
                //CODE FOR NOT CLOSING POPUP
                InvokeContinueWithoutSavePopUp();
            }
            else
            {
                //CODE FOR CLOSING POPUP
                $(this).parent().replaceWith("");
                layerDlg = null;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So...I am opening a Jquery Dialog popUp with the 'Layer' div, when user clicks the 'X' button on the top right of the popUp the code jumps to the 'close()' function...However the popUp is already closed, I only wanted to close the popUp if g_changesMade = FALSE,

IF g_changesMade is TRUE, open InvokeContinueWithoutSavePopUp();, I tried using before close but it didnt hit into that function at all.

So would the resolution be to change the function called when 'X' is clicked to check the value of g_changesMade and perform the necessary logic,
How can I over right the 'x' close then? is this possible?

Comment: try to return false in "close" callback function

Comment: beforeClose should be called before close, In your code "beforecolse" 'c' is in lower case which is not valid function for the jQuery dialog it should be "beforeClose". try this line "beforeClose: function(){ return g_changesMade; }"

Answer (score 0):

First, there's not method called `beforeclose`. It must be `beforeClose` with capital letter **C**

```
function InvokePage() {
    var layerDlg = $("#Layer").dialog({
        position: { my: "top", at: "bottom", of: $("header") },
        height: "auto",
        width: "auto",
        maxWidth: 400,
        modal: true,
        appendTo: "form",
        resizable: false,
        open: function (){},
        beforeClose: function() // <-- capital letter C
        {
            var a = 1;                
        },
        close: function () {
            if (g_changesMade) {
                //CODE FOR NOT CLOSING POPUP
                InvokeContinueWithoutSavePopUp();
            }
            else
            {
                //CODE FOR CLOSING POPUP
                $(this).parent().replaceWith("");
                layerDlg = null;
            }
        }
    });
}
```